# How to reload usercontrol from another form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2

form1 containing usercontrol1, whereas form 2 containing button1.

**Issue:** I want to reload usercontrol1 when button 1 is clicked. I've written some code but got an error,don't know what should I do to fix this.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
         UserControl1 master = (UserControl1)Application.OpenForms["UserControl1"];
          master.UserControl1_Load();
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _"but got error"_ - Are you not allowed to share that error with us?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to cast a `Form` to a `UserControl1`? Unless `UserControl1` (directly or indirectly) inherits from `Form`, I don't see this working.

Comment: in usercontrol1 of form1 containing report , so when i input the data from form2 and save from  button1, how to automatically  refresh my report ,also form 2 is child of form1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i tried this and it's work perfectly.**

in Form1.designer.cs

```
 public UserControl1 userControl11;
```

in Form2

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 master = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
    master.userControl1.UsrControl1_Load();
}
```

in userControl1.cs

```
  public void UsrCont1_Load()
 {
   UserControl1_Load(this, null);
 }
```